# Uniformly sampling positive solutions for intersection of two n-dimensional hyperplanes with strictly positive coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, linear-programming

This question has several variations and is related to Linear programming (but not exactly the same).

I have two equations (in n-dimensions). The first equation is $b^t x = c$. Where  $b$ and $x$ are both n-vectors. $b$ is also element-wise positive. $b > 0$ and $c$ is a positive scalar. The second equation is simply  $\sum x=1$.

I am interested in uniformly sampling all positive solutions to these two equations. In matrix form, we can combine these two equations as

$$Ax=[c; 1]$$

$x>0$

where $A= [ b^t ; 1,1,1,1,... 1 ] \in R^{2 \times n}$ and I have followed the MATLAB notation of denoting a newline by ';'.

Note that the main point of departure with linear programming is that I am not simply looking for 1 candidate solution. I am looking for some analytical ( or semi-analytical) method or insight to uniformly generate solutions.

Additionally, note that if we consider only the second equation $[1,1,1,..1]x=1$ and $x>0$, our problem reduces to the standard simplex or sampling from the Dirchlet distribution.

Is there some way I can use the Dirchelet distribution to add the constraint ($b^t x=c$).

Note that, since b and c are all positive, it is always guaranteed that atleast 1 solution exists inside the simplex.